# IMAP: Discourage client from trying to create mailbox

Tags: imap

I am implementing an IMAP server, operating on messages shared with other systems and due to business needs users are not allowed to create or delete messages or mailboxes via the IMAP server.

In our production environment however, we often see the following three commands occur very often

```
15 EXAMINE "Drafts"

16 STATUS "Drafts"

17 CREATE "Drafts"
```

For all three we reply with a `NO` response, but when the user logs in again next time, we see the same commands being issued.

Is there a way to discourage the client from issuing these commands? The only folder that we have is `INBOX`.

Comment: I sounds as if the client remembers that folder creation (not *mailbox* creation) is denied for the duration of the session, but doesn't persist that to future sessions.  Nothing you can do to force a client to add such tidbits to its data file format.  In summary: The client is right, you're wrong, just decline the commands.

Comment: RFC3501 does not mention folders, they are indeed called mailboxes. Anyway, I thought as you do, but legoscia answered my question.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had this in the above comment... Anyway, the client needs to retry following each login, because continuing to fail after permissions have been changed is a much more user-visible issue than resending a few ignored commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, a [response code](http://www.iana.org/assignments/imap-response-codes/imap-response-codes.xhtml) of `CANNOT` ("The operation violates some invariant of the server and can
         never succeed") should get the message across, though I suspect few clients would react appropriately to such feedback.

Comment: I was not aware of RFC5530. Thank you!

Comment: The client still has to try the command again on the next session, because it can't know whether the server has been upgraded in the interim.